# Sql Server While Loop with Changing Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a User Table in my database that contains two fields

1. user_id
2. manager_id

I am trying to construct a query to list all of the manager_ids that are associated with a user_id in a hierarchical structure.

So if i give a user_id, i will get that users manager, followed by that persons manager all the way to the very top.

So far i have tried but it doesnt give what i need:

```
    WITH cte(user_id, manager_id) as (

    SELECT user_id, manager_id 
    FROM user 
    WHERE manager_id=@userid

    UNION ALL

    SELECT u.user_id,  u.manager_id, 
    FROM user u
    INNER JOIN cte c on e.manager_id = c.employee_id
    )

    INSERT INTO #tbl (manager_id)
    select user_id, manager_id from cte;
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

I thought about a While loop but this may not be very efficient and im not too sure how to implement that.

Comment: I think you are looking for `recursion`.

Comment: What does your subject line have to do with your question?   What is wrong with the results of the query you have posted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP asked for a while loop, and while (ha, pun) this may not be the best way... Ask and you shall receive. (:

Here is sample data I created (in the future, please provide this):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (userID int, managerID int)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1, 3)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (2, 3)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (3, 7)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (4, 6)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (5, 7)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (6, 9)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (7, 10)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (8, 10)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (9, 10)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (10, 12)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (11, 12)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (12, NULL)
```

While Loop:

```
CREATE TABLE #results (userID INT, managerID INT)

DECLARE @currentUser INT = 1    -- Would be your parameter!
DECLARE @maxUser INT
DECLARE @userManager INT
SELECT @maxUser = MAX(userID) FROM #temp

WHILE @currentUser <= @maxUser
    BEGIN
        SELECT @userManager = managerID FROM #temp WHERE userID = @currentUser
        INSERT INTO #results VALUES (@currentUser, @userManager)
        SET @currentUser = @userManager
    END

    SELECT * FROM #results

DROP TABLE #temp
DROP TABLE #results
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i was able to tweak your solution to get mine working.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this column list in your CTE declaration that has nothing to do with the columns you are actually selecting in the CTE:

```
 WITH cte(employee_id, name, reports_to_emp_no, job_number) as (
```

Just make it this:

```
 WITH cte as (
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend recursive solution:

```
WITH Parent AS
(
    SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=@userId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.* FROM user T
    JOIN Parent P ON P.manager_id=T.user_id
)
SELECT * FROM Parent
```

To see demo, run following:

```
SELECT * INTO #t FROM (VALUES (1,NULL),(2,1),(3,2),(4,1)) T(user_id,manager_id);

DECLARE @userId int = 3;

WITH Parent AS
(
    SELECT * FROM #t WHERE user_id=@userId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.* FROM #t T
    JOIN Parent P ON P.manager_id=T.user_id
)
SELECT * FROM Parent
```